# Dota 2 Reborn: Console command for Captain's Mode

Tags: dota-2, source-engine

The console command `dota_force_gamemode 2` used to work for playing Dota 2 in Captain's Mode, but in Dota 2 Reborn the same fails and the game runs in the default mode (All Pick).

- Has the command changed for Reborn? If yes, what's the updated one for Reborn?
- Or the Captain's Mode is currently frozen from being triggered via Console (in Beta)?

Am running the game with the following ProcParams:
`bin/win32/dota2.exe -steam -novid -console +dota_wait_for_players_to_load 1 +dota_force_gamemode 2`

Comment: How are you entering a game? Are you creating a custom lobby, or queueing for a public game?

Comment: Game mode Value is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The console command you are using is for all pick game mode.*dota_force_gamemode 2* . If you want to play captain's mode change the value *2* to *4*. Your console command should look like **dota_force_gamemode 4**.

```
**NUMBER** **MODE**
    2       All Pick
    4       Captain's mode
    8       Random Draft
    16      Single Draft
```

For more information regarding console commands try [Game Modes](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Game_modes)

Comment: @ Rishabh Sharma : I tried the aforementioned modes but the game starts in All Pick. I believe it is the `rev emulator` I am using.